# How can renegotiation (rehandshake) be disabled entirely with openssl, on the server side?

Tags: c, ssl, encryption, openssl, cryptography

I want to refuse/disable all renegotiations initiated from either direction with openssl (in my server code in C).

Is there an option or callback I can set (e.g., `SSL_CTX_set_fooooo()`) to accomplish this? I can find nothing.

I don't understand why an option like `SSL_CTX_set_options(ctx, SSL_OP_NO_SESSION_RESUMPTION_ON_RENEGOTIATION)` is documented but nothing like, say, `SSL_CTX_set_options(ctx, SSL_NO_RENEGOTIATION)`.

Comment: There are two fast start algorithms. I think you are looking for both `SSL_OP_NO_SESSION_RESUMPTION_ON_RENEGOTIATION` and `SSL_OP_NO_TICKET`.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old, but [this comment on an openssl issue](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/8390#issuecomment-491690584) might point future searchers in the right direction:

> SSL3_FLAGS_NO_RENEGOTIATE_CIPHERS is only relevant to OpenSSL 1.0.2 it cannot be used in 1.1.0 or 1.1.1. If you use it then it prevents renegotiation from occurring at all, so there is no need to also use SSL_OP_NO_SESSION_RESUMPTION_ON_RENEGOTIATION. The equivalent option in 1.1.0/1.1.1 is SSL_OP_NO_RENEGOTIATION.

`SSL_OP_NO_RENEGOTIATION` was what I was looking for to disable client renegotiation but secure renegotiation (RFC 5746) was still active, per [testssl](https://testssl.sh/).

Comment: The OP of that thread and me ↑ are the same person, haha. By the time I created that issue I had all but forgotten I asked a similar question here years before; but linking that information here is a good idea. Thanks (+1).

Comment: @will haha, that's hilarious! I'm glad you asked the questions because they pointed me in the right direction also.